# Django: Issue with urls.py in - second pair of eyes needed

Tags: regex, django, url

This is probably only a stupid carelessness bug, but I cannot find the reason. Among others, I have defined this pattern in my urls.py:

```
url(
    r'^edit_assessment/(\w+)/(\d{4})/(\w+)/$',
    'assessment',
    name='edit_assessment'
),
```

Yet, the following URL is not being matched:

```
http://localhost:8000/edit_assessment/hp23/2013/hunting-excursion/
```

Can someone save me from this headache inducing misery?

Comment: yep the name isn't starts with `edit_assessment`

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the comment. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: `([-\w]+)` to match `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^edit_assessment` assumes that the string `edit_assessment` is at the start. Try the below regex to match the above mentioned URL link which contains the string `edit_assessment` and also you need to put the last `\w+` inside character class with `-` so that it would match the string `hunting-excursion`

```
^edit_assessment/(\w+)/(\d{4})/([-\w]+)/$
```

Comment: Normally yes, but Django adds the server url automatically (in this case "http://localhost:8000/"). I used the same beginning for all other URLs without issues

Comment: oh, then remove the starting anchor `edit_assessment/(\w+)/(\d{4})/([-\w]+)/$` see http://regex101.com/r/kA0mL3/3

Comment: I think you should edit your answer with the suggestion in your last comment. Otherwise people with similar questions may run into problems and get stuck as it is not correct using this regex in django.

Comment: @timo.rieber which comment you mean? sorry i don't know about django. So i suggest op with multiple options.

Comment: Your last regex is correct for django and the specific question, `^edit_assessment/(\w+)/(\d{4})/([-\w]+)/$`. See also jrothenbuhler's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The hyphen in "hunting-excursion" isn't matched by `\w`. You should change it to `[-\w]` as Avinash mentioned. Your pattern is otherwise correct, it should not include the protocol and hostname as Django strips these out before matching.

For future reference, http://www.pyregex.com/ is a great tool for testing out URL patterns or any other Python regex.

Comment: Damn... Would have never found it out - it's the first time I used Django's "slugify" method and thought that it wouldn't cause any issues! Thanks!